# How to get rid of for loop in deep layer neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

```
for in range(1,number_layers):
  #vectorised matrix multiplication
  Z1 = np.dot(W1,X)+b
  A1 = np.tanh(Z1)
  ....
```

In the above code for deep layered neural networks, is there any way to get rid of the for loop iterating over hidden layers?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? You could use `functools.reduce` but that comes down to the same thing.

Comment: If I can somehow remove it, I reckon I can train my model faster!!

Comment: Please provide a correct code. E.g. you are missing the loop variable.  Most likely there is a solution, but need some working example to be able to help.

Comment: you could use a lambda function

Comment: Thank you. Let me check if it results in faster execution..

Comment: @SachinPrabhu I guess that your number of hidden layers is fairly small so the loop shouldn't add too much to it. In any case you can use tensorflow for static graph creation.

Comment: @a_guest Yes. I'm starting with 3 layers only as of now. Thank you.